# How to enable facebook login on ios & android with the same account

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-login

I just created an iOS app with a facebook login, I can login with my facebook account and everything is working perfect on this app. The problem came when i built the same app for android, when i try to login with facebook, it gives me an error about the hash key. If i delete the permission on my facebook account about my app, it enables me the login with my android app and disables the ios login.

So, how can i enable both logins in both iOS and Android?

I am using iOS on production mode and android on debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can add android plateform where you have created the app for iOS. Under the settings tab you can add plateform and package name of your project. So that you can use the same appID for iPhone and Android application.

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes, i am actually doing this. But the key hash error persist on Android only when i first login on iOS

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple platform support under same AppId. App both your apps with unique identifier in app id

Comment: yes, i am actually doing this. But the key hash error persist on Android only when i first login on iOS